# Restrict Wordpress Search to Custom Field

Tags: custom-field, search

I am endeavouring to have wordpress search in one custom field, and no other post text or attributes.  The site has a very specific function which is to return posts having an exact match on the first letter(s) of a UK postcode in a custom field.  No other searching is required.

So each post represents an engineering company which has a number of UK postcodes set against it.  When the site user searches for a specific postcode it should return all posts with that code present.

I am using the Advanced Custom Fields Plugin

I have tried this code in my child theme functions.php

```
function __search_by_postcode_only( $search, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( empty( $search ) )
        return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query
    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
    $n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';
    $search =
    $searchand = '';
    foreach ( (array) $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
        $term = esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) );
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.search_post_code LIKE '{$n}      {$term}{$n}')";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }
    if ( ! empty( $search ) ) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
    }
    return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', '__search_by_postcode_only', 500, 2 );
```

Where search_post_code is the custom field in question which can have multiple values.

I have tried other enhanced search plugins but they all seem to search Post Title and Post Content as well.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

On WordPress you can filter searches when accessing the URL with an additional parameter on the end for example;

```
https://www.your-website.com/?s=search-query&post_type=custom_post_type_name
```

If you are accessing this URL from a search box / form on your website, add in the following hidden field;

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post type name" />
```

Comment: The OP wants to query a custom field. They aren't accessible just by adding a query string. To the URL.